# Github Actions Build fails for Nextjs giving :Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: node.js, next.js, github-actions, yarn-v2

GitHub Actions Build fails for the Nextjs, I have the following GitHub workflow File :

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
    # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Install NodeJS
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: '16.16.0'
    
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: borales/actions-yarn@v3.0.0
      with:
        cmd: install # will run `yarn install` command
    - uses: borales/actions-yarn@v3.0.0
      name: lint React App
      with:
        cmd: lint # will run `yarn run lint` command
    - uses: borales/actions-yarn@v3.0.0
      name: Build React App
      with:
        cmd: build # will run `yarn build` command
```

I have changed the Nodejs version to 16.16.0 but even then it continuously giving

```
node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.hashFactory (/github/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:138971:18)
    at BulkUpdateDecorator.update (/github/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:138872:50)
    at /github/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59321:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:442:9) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.12.0
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what is the cause of this error, however I managed to get it fixed by dropping [borales/actions-yarn](https://github.com/Borales/actions-yarn) and using [actions/setup-node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) instead. It is suggested in the actions-yarn documentation itself, it now only exists to support existing flows. Therefore this might work for you:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Install NodeJS
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: '16.16.0'
        cache: 'yarn'
    

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: yarn install

    - name: lint React App
      run: yarn lint

    - name Build React App
      run:yarn build
```

Comment: you are really the MVP, thank you so much! In my case, I had to delete the line with cache because I didn't have yarn.lock